# Select2 ajax preselection with custom data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So I have a multiselection dropdown with select2 and I fetch the info from a database. The thing is that prepopulating the dropdown with many values works with the example from the docs, but I also want to include an extra data field. This is how I try to populate the dropdown:

```
var productSelect = $('#product_ids');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ajaxOrdersData/' + orderID
    }).then(function (datas) {        
        datas.forEach(data => {
            var option = new Option(data.name, data.id, true, true);
            option.dataset.price = data.price;      
            productSelect.append(option).trigger('change');
        });     
        productSelect.trigger({
            type: 'select2:select',
            params: {
                data: datas.map(function (item) {                       
                    return {
                        text: item.nfame,
                        id: item.id,
                        price: item.price,
                    }
                })      
            }
        });
    });
```

The above code does create an option tag with a data-price value but then, retrieving that value like below, doesn't work:

```
var products = $('#product_ids').select2('data');
```

The products variable doesn't have the price data attribute.

What other ways there are for me to fetch the price data attribute of all products in multiselect when clicking on a button on the DOM?

Comment: Try `$().data('price')`.. Have to deal with Select2 & $ at work.. not a fan.

Comment: Yeah that actually works but how to iterate through many products?

Comment: I have a hard time remembering exactly, but when setting up the select2 element you specify an array where the selected options get pushed to. We also use knockout in our stack so I doubt my exactl solution will be of much help to you.. and in case I misunderstood you, all your entries are in `productSelect.children` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution I came up with:

```
 var products =$('#product_ids option:selected');
```

And then to retrieve the value:

```
 $.each(products, function(index, value) {            
            actualTotals += Number(value.dataset.price);            
        });
```

An alternative solution is to keep the .select2('data'); way of fetching the selections but instead use jquery to retrieve each elements attributes from the resulting object:

```
var products =$('#product_ids').select2('data'); 
$.each(products, function(index, value) {            
                price = value.element.attributes['data-price'].value;         
});
```